# res. topnav position under the header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to convert a top navigation so that I can use it as horizontal navigation below a header.

I would like to achieve the following ;

- remove .brand-title (this leads to problems)
  -center .navbar-links  (justify-content: center;&align-items: center; don´t work)
  -center .toggle-button

How do I get there? I find it very difficult with responsive CSS.

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
}

.brand-title {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: .5rem;
}

.navbar-links {
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar-links ul {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.navbar-links li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

.toggle-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: .75rem;
    right: 1rem;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 30px;
    height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .navbar {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }

    .toggle-button {
        display: flex;
    }

    .navbar-links {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .navbar-links ul {
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .navbar-links ul li {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .navbar-links ul li a {
        padding: .5rem 1rem;
    }

    .navbar-links.active {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="background_styles.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      <script src="script.js" defer></script>
      <title>Responsive Navbar</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="brand-title">Brand Name</div>
        <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-links">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what result you want

Comment: I would like to remove the title (brand-title) and align the menu and the toogle button in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to get such a result?

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
}

.navbar-links {
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar-links ul {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.navbar-links li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

.toggle-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: .75rem;
    right: 1rem;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 30px;
    height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .navbar {
        height: 50px;
    }

    .toggle-button {
        display: flex;
        
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .navbar-links {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
    }

    .navbar-links ul {
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .navbar-links ul li {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #333;
    }

    .navbar-links ul li a {
        padding: .5rem 1rem;
    }

    .navbar-links.active {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="background_styles.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      <script src="script.js" defer></script>
      <title>Responsive Navbar</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <nav class="navbar">
        <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-links">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```